# calling asmx service from php using cURL or similar?

Tags: php, web-services, curl, asmx

I would like to call a webservice from this page : http://badmintonpeople.dk/DBF/HoldTurnering/Stilling/ through php, so that I can get some id's of the teams present in my sportsclub.

The service url is: http://badmintonpeople.dk/SportsResults/Components/WebService1.asmx/GetLeagueStanding

And if I push the "søg" button on the page, I see that the variables I send are: 
{"callbackcontextkey":"A99DADC1F9E901007E51592E8C0838916CF337E7613986982B4649B3EFBA0844D2DC6B4A5BE1FA47827E6036CB6A819E","subPage":"6","seasonID":"2014","leagueGroupID":"","ageGroupID":"","regionID":"","leagueGroupTeamID":"","leagueMatchID":"","clubID":"1617","playerID":""}

I've tried to fetch the data I get returned from the service through cURL and SOAPclient, but I can't seem to figure it out :-(

Can anyone solve this puzzle for me, then I would be VERY grateful, cause to me it looks like I have to give it up :-/

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a problem with your service. Once your service is fixed and you know its working (you may check it with WCFClient from Visual Studio 2013), use the source xml generated from WCFClient and post it to the server using proper headers.